# How do plugins identify what type of server a website is running on?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webserver, identification

I have tested a few plugins for Firefox and Chrome which can identify IP number of a given website ofcause. But some of them can also show what server-side technology the website runs on.

How do they do this? I know about client-user-agent, is there something similar in the HTTP protocol where the server sendes a "server-host-agent" kinda string?

And if so, how would the code for retreiving this look. I guess its something with WebClient?

Anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect web server type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097472/how-to-detect-web-server-type)

Comment: ohh! I didnt find that one, eventhough I tried before posting. Sorry and thanks for the link. Will check that one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `HttpWebRequest` and setting the `Method` property to `HEAD`, you can do a HTTP HEAD request, which is very lightweight. It will return the HTTP Headers (which may or may not be correct). They HTTP Headers may also differ from server to server as there is no standard for what headers a server should expose.

The code:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/");
myReq.Method = "HEAD";
WebResponse myRes = myReq.GetResponse();
for(int i=0; i < myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Count; ++i) {
   Console.WriteLine(
      "\nHeader Name:{0}, Value :{1}", 
      myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Keys[i], myHttpWebResponse.Headers[i]
   ); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.http500.com");
try
{
    var response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    // Safe cast to HttpWebResponse using 'as', will return null if unsuccessful
    var httpWebResponse = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    if(httpWebResponse != null)
    {
        var httpStatusCode = httpWebResponse.StatusCode;
        // HttpStatusCode is an enum, cast it to int for its actual value
        var httpStatusCodeInt = (int)httpWebResponse.StatusCode;                    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I found out something similar while waiting, but I used GET and that produced the whole HTML page in the GET response, which could be quite an overkill for large webpages. Thanks again!

Comment: I've tried using HTTPS addresses too, they seem to crash or something?

Comment: Crash? Do you get any details in the exception? Use Fiddler to study the details of requests you make with your browser and the responses you get. That will make you able to determine what's going on.

Comment: ok, thanks for idea with Fiddler. Now I want to handle the exceptions, because anything but a perfect URL works. Eg. a 404 crashes...

Comment: Ah, now I understand what's happening. Yes, you need to catch `WebException` at least. Check out the docs on what exceptions `GetResponse()` might throw: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Comment: yes, I found similar articles about this. Now I only need to figure out the HTTP ERROR CODE VALUE. I keep getting the StatusCode as "OK" or "Not Found" ... I want 404, 200, 302, 301 etc. that will be my last question within this thread, if you can provide the answer :o) Promise!